# Merging two/three records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, merge, merging-data

I want to merge two profiles into one. What is the best way to do this in Rails.

I have two profiles say `user1` and `user2` and there are at least 30 tables associated with them.

Now i want to **merge them together** so that there should be one profile say `user1` and `user2` should **get deleted** but **all the associated data of `user2`** now should **associate with `user1`**.

For example: suppose `user2` has two contacts and `user1` has 3 contacts after merging user `user1` should have 5 contacts.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this

```
@user1 = User.find(1);
@user2 = User.find(2);

Contact.where("user_id = ?", @user2.id).update_all(:user_id => @user1.id)
@user2.destroy
```

in case of generalize solution
place file /lib/acts_as_user_merge.rb

```
module UserMerge
  module ActsAsUserMerge
    module Base
      def self.included(klass)
        klass.class_eval do
          extend Config
        end
      end
    end

    module Config
        def acts_as_user_merge
            include ::UserMerge::ActsAsUserMerge::InstanceMethods
        end
    end

    module InstanceMethods    
      def merge(user)
        models = Array.new
        models_names = User.reflections.collect{|a, b| b.class_name if b.macro==:has_many}.compact
        models_names.each do |name|
          models << Object.const_get name
        end
        models.each do |model|
          model.where("user_id = ?", user.id).update_all(:user_id => self.id)
        end
        user.destroy
      end
    end
  end
end

::ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ::UserMerge::ActsAsUserMerge::Base
```

how to use

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many ...

  acts_as_user_merge

end

@user1.merge(@user2)
```

kinda messy and not tested but should give you an idea

Comment: I want some generalize solution....i don't want to do it for all my 30   associations

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
def merge_users(dead, user)
  User.reflections.each do |assoc, reflection|
    foreign_key = reflection.foreign_key
    case reflection.macro
    when :has_many, :has_one then
      unless reflection.options[:through]
        reflection.klass.where(foreign_key => dead.id).update_all(foreign_key => user.id) # if id is a primary key
      end
      if options[:as] # polymorphic
        if reflection.macro == :has_many
          dead.send("#{options[:as].pluralize}")).each { |r| user.send("#{options[:as].pluralize}<<", r) }
        else
          user.send("#{options[:as]}=", dead.send("#{options[:as]}"))
          user.save
        end
      end
    when :belongs_to then
      if options[:polymorphic]
        user.send("#{assoc}=", deaf.send(assoc))
        user.save
      else
        user.update_attribute(foreign_key, dead.send(foreign_key))
      end
    when :has_and_belongs_to_many then
      dead.send("#{assoc}")).each { |r| user.send("#{assoc}<<", r) }
    end

  end
end

merge_users(dead_user, user)
dead_user.destroy
```